# Writing SQL query in another method [SQL PLUS]

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Tables (GRADES,COURSES) and i need to find the COURSE_ID with the Maximum Average of all Averages of Courses Grades

Example :

```
DBASE COURSE GRADES : 90,60,90,100 (AVGERAGE=85)
DSTRUCT COURSE GRADES : 100,100,100,100 (AVERAGE=100)
C# COURSE GRADES : 50,50,60,60 (AVERAGE = 55)
```

So i should get the `COURSE_ID` of the course (DSTRUCT) which its the MAXIMUM average of all averages

So i have this code (I didn't write it) , and i need to write it without assigning "c" and "g" and "g1"

```
SELECT g.course_id
  FROM (SELECT  course_id, avg(grade) AS average FROM grades GROUP BY course_id) g
 WHERE g.average = (
      SELECT max(g1.average)
        FROM (SELECT course_id, avg(grade) AS average FROM grades GROUP BY course_id) g1
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this way of doing it, but it's the only way I can think of that meets the extreme criteria that you have laid down.  For anyone needing this in the future, please look at my OTHER answer, not this one.

```
SELECT course_id, AVG(grade) 
FROM   grades
GROUP BY course_id 
HAVING AVG(grade) >= ALL (
    SELECT AVG(grade) 
    FROM   grades
    GROUP BY course_id )
```

Comment: I am sorry , but we didn't learn "ALL" too .. and i only need to display the "COURSE_ID" (no need to display the average)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT course_id, AVG(grade) 
FROM   grades
GROUP BY course_id
ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I need the same code i wrote but with out assigning "g" "c" "g1" , i know that your code is easier but i didn't learn this stuff so i need a code without using limit and desc

Comment: Well thanks , but i have an exam and i cant use stuff that i didn't learn :\

Comment: OK, I'll post a second answer.  Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Won't probably work for Waseem as the title says "SQL PLUS" which indicates he is using Oracle which does not support `LIMIT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ooh, good point.  OK, well I'll leave it here in case others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be your answer

```
SELECT course_id
  FROM (SELECT course_id, AVG(grade)
          FROM grades
         GROUP BY course
         ORDER BY AVG(grade) DESC)
 WHERE rownum = 1;
```